# Who generally provides a device driver?

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I am curious as to who provides a device driver,

Is it the hardware manufacturer, operating system distribution or ?

I am looking in FPGA design and curious as to who actually provides a driver for the peripherals (flash, Ethernet, etc.) or do I need to write them? This is assuming I want to run a full operating system on an FPGA CPU.

Comment: All of the above.

Comment: This is actually a good question that few "super users" know the facts of.

Comment: Device drivers are provided by the person who writes the device driver.  For large and well supported systems that can be the manufacturer, for small systems and highly custom platforms, especially FPGA platforms, it is often up to the person writing the software for that device to make the device driver.  The only real answer you can get is "It depends".

Comment: In most cases, answers that would begin, "It depends..." tend to be too broad.  In this case, there are a number of common routes.    However, the question has been answered in 4 words by DavidPostill, in a single paragraph by Mokubai, and in a few paragraphs in several answers.  I agree with Jason's comment, so voting to reopen.

Comment: I concede, despite being a good question, it might not be a good question for SU.  To answer properly would be more of a guide than a specific answer.

Comment: @Jason, curious why you deleted your answer.

Comment: The manufacturer develops the driver and either hands it to the user or to the OS distributor. Sometimes there are no drivers provided for configuration X so that people reverse-engineer a driver.

Comment: @fixer1234 I wrote in a hurry and it was down-voted.  If I find the time I will write a much better answer.

Answer (score 2):

A device driver is used so the Operating System can communicate with the hardware.

It is logical to understand that, in order for the manufacturer to be able to develop the hardware, and to test it, they also have to interface and thus work with the device driver part.

Does this automatically mean they will provide the driver? No. Because most hardware use certain chipsets, these chipsets often come with drivers themselves, and they can be used to work with the hardware already out of the box.

Due to the development of streamlining this process, generic drivers have been made which can power many devices. These generic drivers are usually also bundled with operating systems to support a feature called "Plug and Play".

For a hardware manufacturer, the question remains: Is it possible to use these generic drivers, and thus not require additional software to be installed, or does the hardware have a unique feature that requires additional software to be run?

So basically, depending on how the hardware works, it depends on who provided the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Device drivers are developed by device manufacturers and are provided by operating system update and with your pc in a DVD.

If your pc has a device connected without drivers Windows update downloads drivers and install them for proper functioning of the device.

Every device has a unique model number and manufacturer details such as website, company which helps in getting proper drivers.

I think everything is connected in someway to provide you better services.